# Wait for prior fetch to finish aborting before proceeding

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

Right now I have code that is basically:

```js
var loadingIndicator = /* Reference to UI component */,
    output = /* Reference to UI component */,
    abortController;

function onThingRequested(thing) {
    abortController?.abort();
    requestThing(thing);
}

async function requestThing(thing) {
    abortController = new AbortController();
    output.innerText = '';
    loadingIndicator.show();
    try {
        console.log(`STARTING ${thing}`);
        // For the sake of brevity of the example, assume `thing` is safe to put here.
        var thingRes = await fetch(`/example?thing=${thing}`, { signal: abortController.signal });
        output.innerText = await thingRes.text();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`ERRORED ${thing}`);
        output.innerText = err;
    } finally {
        console.log(`FINALLY'D ${thing}`);
        loadingIndicator.hide();
    }
}
```

If I trigger `onThingRequested('thing1')` and then, before it loads, trigger `onThingRequested('thing2')`, the output is, of course...

```
STARTED thing1
STARTED thing2
ERRORED thing1
FINALLY'D thing1
FINALLY'D thing2
```

...because `requestThing` triggers the new fetch immediately, while the abort happens asynchronously.  Is there any elegant way to wait for the prior fetch to finish aborting before proceeding?  Besides, of course, the hacky-feeling workaround of...

```js
function onThingRequested(thing) {
    abortController?.abort();
    setTimeout(() => requestThing(thing), 1);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to wait for the abort to finalize before making the next request? It's aborted so just move on. If you must, you may do like `fetch(whatever,{signal: abortController.signal}).then(doStgWithWhatverResult).catch(e => (console.log(e), fetch(nextWhatever)));`

Comment: The requests come in response to user input, so it needs to abort if the user cancels it or makes xer next request before the previous one completes, but it cannot assume what the next request will be or that there necessarily is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/abort_event) event to check if the fetch request has been aborted before calling `requestThing` again.

```
function onThingRequested(thing) {
  if (!abortController) {
    requestThing(thing);
    return;
  }

  abortController.signal.onabort = () => {
    requestThing(thing);
  };

  abortController.abort();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does feel less hacky!  I just wish it did not add so much additional code to the function.

Comment: In my opinion, this is as short as it gets without sacrificing readability. You could still make them one-liners, if you want, and bring the whole thing back to 3 lines of code in your function. Be sure to accept the answer if it solved your question.